# What does "x = 1 default" actually mean?

Tags: math-software

For context, I am a programmer, not a mathematician, so please forgive my math-ignorance.

I am implementing [this](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_DeltaE_CIE2000.html) calculation in an application that I am working on, but at the bottom of the page, I came across something I have not seen before.

Towards the end of the equation in points (26, 27 & 28) 3 items are individually defined as equaling 1 default. Is there any special meaning here? or can I just set their value to be 1?

Thanks!

Comment: The "syntax" depends on the programming language used, but - in general - [default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_(computer_science))  : "refers to the preexisting value of a user-configurable setting that is assigned to a software application, computer program or device."

Comment: I think the meaning of "default" is that $K_L, K_C, K_H$ usually take the value $1$, but may be given values other than $1$ if a slightly different model for $\Delta E$ is required. If you are implementing the $\Delta E$ calculation as a function you could make $K_L, K_C, K_H$ optional parameters which all default to a value of $1$ unless the user specifies some other value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

I took a peek at the javascript implementation for the [calculator on the same site](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_DeltaE_CIE2000.html).

it turns out to be just as straight forward as it looks:

```
var kL = 1.0;
var kC = 1.0;
var kH = 1.0;
```